# Select a range of cells, delete the empty ones, and then add border around remaining cells

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use a macro that will look at a range of cells, delete out the empty rows, and then add a border around the remaining cells that actually has content. Here are two macros I have: One is for removing the empty cells, and the other is to add borders. As I mentioned, the issue is, I do not know how to tell Excel to only add a border around the cells that were left over after the Remove macro was completed. I would appreciate any help.

```
**Sub Remove()**
'
' Remove Macro
'

'
    Range("B80:B95").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
    Range("B61:B77").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
    Range("B39:B58").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-27
    Range("B10:B28").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
End Sub
```

and

```
**Sub Border()**
'
' Border Macro
'

'
    Range("B7:K19").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    Range("B21:K74").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=54
    Range("O76").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-81
End Sub
```

Comment: Quick note - there's no point in a comment that says "remove" when the title of the sub is "remove_macro"; it adds no useful info.

Comment: I actually don't even remember writing that in there so I have no idea where that came from. Thanks for pointing that out though. Any suggestions on the problem I am trying to solve?

Comment: Do you need to look through all of column B for empty cells or just the ranges you specified?

Comment: Just the ranges I specified

Answer (score 0):

I assume your B to K columns will always remain constant. You basically just want to find the total "used" rows...

```
Dim cols As Integer, LastRow As Long, TestRow As Long

LastRow = 0
For cols = 2 to 11
    TestRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
    If TestRow > LastRow Then LastRow = TestRow
Next cols

Range("B7:K" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
Range("B21:K74").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=54
Range("O76").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-81
```

I really hate the use of `.Select` but I am not rewriting all your other code.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will replacing both my Remove and Border code with the one you provided above work?

Comment: @AhmadA. You still need your remove code... This is only to address the issue you mentioned with the border code.

Comment: I switched it out with my border code but it's first highlighting "For cols - 2 to 11" in red and throws an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AhmadA. Fixed.  Should have been an equals sign.

Comment: It's almost there. Let me try to explain what it looks like since I can't post an image. I've got three main sections. Each originally had extra rows so I got rid of them and wanted the border around the item on each subsection. So for example: my first subsection ends with something that says "depuck to tote line" and then there's a space and then it's the next section. I want the border to encompass and end at "Depuck to tote line". The code I just put in is also including that extra space I left between sections into the border. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AhmadA. Post your screenshots on an image sharing site and add the link to your question via an edit.  I will then edit the actual picture into the post.

Comment: seems like I'll have to do it from my personal computer since image sharing websites are blocked from my work computer for some reason. I'll get back to you in a few hours. I really appreciate your help with all of this. Talk soon

Comment: I figured a way to get the image up. Here you go: http://s22.postimg.org/9e4fysnip/Capture.png   .... As I mentioned, I would want row 20 to be the empty row with row 19 and 21 bordered out. Similarly, the other rows that follow under neath that need to follow that same format is row 75

Comment: I figured a way to get the image up. Here you go: s22.postimg.org/9e4fysnip/Capture.png .... As I mentioned, I would want row 20 to be the empty row with row 19 and 21 bordered out. Similarly, the other rows that follow under neath that need to follow that same format is row 75 @Chrismas007

Comment: @Chrismas007 - Do you know if you can reduce the lines needed for the `.Borders` part? I always hate having to do basically four iterations of the same block, only because I have to change `.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)` to `.Borders(xlEdgeRight/Top/etc)`.  Can you put `xlEdgeBottom, exEdgeRight, etc` into an array and loop through the array with like `With Selection.Borders(myArray(i))`?  then increase `i`, saving you space? (Does that make sense?)  Edit: Just tried - nope, you can't.

Comment: @Chrismas007. Hi Chrismas, did you get a chance to read my earlier question I had that had the image attached?